# How can I define a property type as being a list (list, set, array, collection) of string in my YAML Swagger definition

Tags: collections, yaml, swagger

I am writing a swagger definition file for an API. The API is a for a GET request

```
/path/to/my/api:
  get:
    summary: My Custom API
    description: |
      Gets a List of FooBar IDs
    produces:
      - application/json
    tags:
      - FooBar
    responses:
      "200":
        description: successful operation
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/MyCustomType"
```

...

```
MyCustomType:
  type: object
  properties: 
    myCustomObject
      type: ??? # list of string?
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For a list of strings, you can describe as follows:

```
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
```

Ref: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#schemaObject

Example:

- https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml#L93-L100 (OpenAPI v2)
- https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/3_0/petstore.yaml#L71-L78 (OpenAPI v3)

Comment: the given example is for array/list, how about set? couldn't get a clue from google

Answer (score 4):

None of these comments really seem to answer the question -- How do you define a SET of items in OpenAPI/Swagger?

- An array of strings is not the same as a SET
- An array of unique strings is not the same as SET

A set is essentially an array of unrepeated enum values.

Given possible string values of `facebook`, `pinterest`, `twitter`, a field named `share_type` could have values containing one or more of them, ex:

**Valid**

`facebook`
`twitter`
`facebook, twitter`
`facebook, twitter, pinterest`

**Invalid Items**

`instagram`
`facebook, instagram`
`pinterest, pinterest`

Another important distinction is that the values cannot be repeated. This is where the `uniqueItems` directive can be helpful.

So given the example above, here is what that OpenAPI spec might look like:

```yaml
share_type:
  type: array
  uniqueItems: true
  items:
    type: string
    enum:
      - facebook
      - pinterest
      - twitter
```

Comment: In programming when we talk about a set it IS an array of unique elements depending on how equality has been defined for those elements. It is not limited to the scope of the posible values of an enum. Indeed you can use any type of item with uniqueItems: true, it doesn't need to be an enum and if you use an openapi generator it will use a Set instead of a List